# php on local machine not behaving what am I overlooking?

Tags: php, localhost

So php on local machine is not rendering a page at all, what am I overlooking?

info.php outputs as expected.
test.php with only the following code is waiting for localhost forever.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php echo "hello world"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

By waiting forever I mean the browser status says: "waiting for localhost"

Can anyone turn on the light please?

Comment: Could you please show us the content of `info.php` and `test.php`?

Comment: when you say localhost waiting forever, i'm guessing its taking a long time to serve the .php file which are info.php and test.php? what else is in the source? echoing texts and phpinfo doesn't hold anything up unless making remote connections or connecting internally to something separate. Have you tried loading a simple .html page with your localhost and see if this problem exists?

Comment: Well a long time means it still now (since before I posted this question) has status "waiting for localhost" There is nothing else in the code i.e 
<html>
<body>
<?php 
echo "hello world"; ?>
</body>
</html>
both files are the same except that info.php of course has phpinfo(); instead of the echo line. incidentally I have also tried without the html envelope.

Comment: In case I wasn't clear info.php displays immediately

Comment: Maybe the edit of my post could have been better. I believe I had a newline between '...as expected' (which should have had a full stop after it) and 'test.php...' but now it looks like a continuation of the same sentence. No wonder @unixmiah appears to have misunderstood my meaning!

Comment: As regards the question about simple html. Yes it works as expected.

Comment: I know this is a wierd one but surely someone must have experienced it. Anyone please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files are not displaying because I have edited and re-saved the file, after having displayed it once and prior to restarting the server. Restarting Apache appears to release this!